# nvim and vim not recognized after upgrade to nightly

Tags: vim, command-line, neovim, appimage

in the attempt of upgrading `nvim`

```sh
NVIM v0.4.4
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compilation: /usr/bin/cc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/neovim-u4YhjF/neovim-0.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DDISABLE_LOG -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -O2 -DNDEBUG -DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wmissing-prototypes -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong -fno-common -fdiagnostics-color=always -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNVIM_MSGPACK_HAS_FLOAT32 -DNVIM_UNIBI_HAS_VAR_FROM -I/build/neovim-u4YhjF/neovim-0.4.4/build/config -I/build/neovim-u4YhjF/neovim-0.4.4/src -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -I/build/neovim-u4YhjF/neovim-0.4.4/build/src/nvim/auto -I/build/neovim-u4YhjF/neovim-0.4.4/build/include
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org

Features: +acl +iconv +tui
See ":help feature-compile"

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

from `latest` to `nightly` (beccause `lsp`)
I ran the command below

```
sudo apt remove neovim
rm -rf ~/.config/nvim/
curl -LO https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/download/nightly/nvim.appimage
chmod u+x nvim.appimage
./nvim.appimage
```

which seems to succeed as nvim opens up

but then I have this result when I try to use it

```sh
$ nvim .
Command 'nvim' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install nvim    # version v0.4.4-stable, or
sudo apt  install neovim  # version 0.4.4-1
See 'snap info nvim' for additional versions.
$ nvim --version
Command 'nvim' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install nvim    # version v0.4.4-stable, or
sudo apt  install neovim  # version 0.4.4-1
See 'snap info nvim' for additional versions.
```

why so?
Should I add `appimage` on my path? (How?)

curiously it killed regular `vim` as well

```sh
$ vim .
Command 'vim' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install vim         # version 2:8.2.2434-1ubuntu1, or
sudo apt install vim-tiny    # version 2:8.2.2434-1ubuntu1
sudo apt install neovim      # version 0.4.4-1
sudo apt install vim-athena  # version 2:8.2.2434-1ubuntu1
sudo apt install vim-gtk3    # version 2:8.2.2434-1ubuntu1
sudo apt install vim-nox     # version 2:8.2.2434-1ubuntu1
```

#### update

after patching the problem
adding to my `bashrc` `alias nvim="./nvim.appimage"`

I still don't know why my (regular) vim disappered
and I also noticed `"+P` `"+Y` don't paste from clipboard anymore

(opened a specific question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67598285/cannot-paste-from-clipboard-in-neovim-nightly))

Comment: You removed (neo)vim, so it's no longer installed. The way you install the new version does not integrate into your package manager. So yes, if you want to keep this version, you'll need to put/symlink it into a folder in your `$PATH`.

Comment: I did this `alias nvim="./nvim.appimage"` but feels wrong, Anyway, why regular vim died?

Comment: Because of `sudo apt remove neovim`, I assume it also installs itself under the name `vim`? The way I'd do it is to create a new folder `~/bin/`, in which I'd symlink the new neovim executable, and then put something like `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"` in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: worked very well... if you make it in an answer I'll accept it right away
I believe the clipboard problem is unrelated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `neovim` of your package manager provided the commands `nvim` (and possibly `vim` as well).

After removing the package via `sudo apt remove neovim`, those commands will be gone. Just by downloading a new version (outside the comfort of your package manager), you won't get a "command" installed. If you want to keep using this downloaded version, the easiest way to do so IMO would be to:

1. Move or symlink the new executable to some new folder like `~/bin`:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
mv nvim.appimage ~/bin/nvim
# or
ln -s ~/Downloads/nvim.appimage ~/bin/nvim
```

2. Add this folder to your path, for example by changing your path in your `.bashrc`:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"' >>~/.bashrc
```

3. Open a new terminal to make the changes take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Couple years late but vim was probably aliased to nvim as many tutorials suggest it and it’s forgotten later on. So vim was likely still installed but had been aliased and had no valid path.