# cannot paste from clipboard in neovim nightly

Tags: neovim

after uninstalling `latest` and installed `nightly` I cannot paste from clipboard,
double checked my ***init.vim*** for `set clipboard=unnamedplus`

any suggestion?

update 21st May

following Matt's comment, running `:checkhealth provider` outputs

```
health#provider#check
========================================================================
## Clipboard (optional)
  - WARNING: No clipboard tool found. Clipboard registers (`"+` and `"*`) will not work.
    - ADVICE:
      - :help clipboard
```

so I run `sudo apt-get install -y xclip`

and works well (even with wayland!)

```
health#provider#check
========================================================================
## Clipboard (optional)
  - OK: Clipboard tool found: xclip
```

Comment: `:checkhealth provider`

Comment: fixed thanks to you, if you make it an answer I'll accept it immediately

Comment: I'm surprised that I didn't have any clipboard provider that neovim could use automatically. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. I had `xclipboard` installed by default. I too installed `xclip` and neovim was happy again.

Comment: It works as mentioned. running actualy LazyVim in `Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neovim doesn't have any code to access OS clipboard directly (or to process X Window events). Instead it delegates to external utilities/plugins. You're expected to execute `:checkhealth` command to see the current state. If you don't have any supported tool on your `PATH` then you'll not be able to access the clipboard.

As a shameless plug, I wrote [plugin](https://github.com/matveyt/neoclip) that consists of dynamic library providing direct access to clipboard. This is to avoid extra process creation for every copy/paste operation (btw. setting `clipboard=unnamed[plus]` is bad for more than just this single reason). However, the library must be built from source before use.

As of Wayland, its IPC mechanism is clearly different from X but at least in GNOME or KDE you may expect both selections being synchronized transparently. Otherwise you need specific utils to access Wayland clipboard, such as wl-copy/wl-paste.